# SQL Design: Is it wise to have a table for current orders and one with all orders for historical purposes?

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm thinking my table is going to get huge as days go by and more orders come in. Should I keep all orders in that same table forever or should I have a table for current orders and one for previous/finished orders since the current orders are the only ones that will be grabbed frequently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep separate table for previous/finished orders then when required you need to apply conditional joins or union.

according to me, rather than that, add one attribute say

```
(
     ...
     ...
     IsArchived       Bit
)
```

which is set to 0 (false) for current/latest order and 1 (true) for finished/previous orders, which will be faster than conditional joins or union at later on.

Comment: Depending on the rdbms, it might be possible to add filtered indexes to improve select performance the orders table, by filtering the relevant indexes on `IsArchived = 0`.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks, much appreciated